# Leaflet : how to resize SVG marker according to zoom (i.e. marker constant size in meters)

Tags: leaflet, size, zooming, marker

I have a map with 20 markers on a geojson layer. They are all from the same SVG and represent a certain area on the map (meaning they represent a circle of constant radius in meter on the map). I need these marker to adapt their size according to zoom level.

I've tried to use a circle as a marker. But my marker needs to be a SVG because it is complex graphic and radius doesn't apply to markers.

Here's the piece of code used to display the markers. Latitude, Longitude and rotationAngle are parsed from a .csv sheet:

```
for (i in chapters) {
        var c = chapters[i];
        if (!isNaN(parseFloat(c['Latitude'])) && !isNaN(parseFloat(c['Longitude']))) {
            var lat = parseFloat(c['Latitude']);
            var lon = parseFloat(c['Longitude']);
            var cercleDirection = parseFloat(c['Direction']);
            var photoIcon = L.icon({
                                iconUrl: 'media/Cercle.svg',
                                iconSize: [220, 220],
                                iconAnchor: [110, 110],
                            });
            markers.push(
                L.marker([lat, lon], {
                    icon: photoIcon,
                    rotationAngle: cercleDirection

                }));
        }
```

[image: Circle are same SVG but different orientation. So far, their size remains the same on screen regardless of zoom level]

Comment: https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#circle - that's an SVG underneath thanks to https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#svg and https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.5.0.html#map-renderer . Please rephrase your question.

Comment: You mean I can use radius with a SVG marker ? How come ?

Comment: I think IvanSanchez implies that you mistake Leaflet Circle and Marker / CircleMarker. If you need something more complex, you should probably provide more details and some code with sample SVG.